# Android Grid Layout Manager column span

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-gridlayout

I need custom keyboard for Android TV, like this one on the image bellow.
The layout has one Recycler View with Grid Layout Manager to customize the rows and columns.

But when I run the app Layout doesn't show the correct width of buttons in the last row. The "Space" button should have span of 4, "Shift" button 2 and "Zero" button 3.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this:

```
    gridLayoutManager.setSpanSizeLookup(new GridLayoutManager.SpanSizeLookup() {
        @Override
        public int getSpanSize(int position) {
            return kbAdapter.getItemViewType(position);
        }
    });
```

Comment: That saved the day!

Comment: I didn't have access to the element by position and tying the logic to item view type solved it for me. Just needed to set itemViewType to the desired span instead of a random constant